# How to list all the files owned by a given user for quota checking?

Tags: filesystems, quota

Is there a way to have a list of all the files owned by a certain user
in a filesystem, and their sizes? I mean, not by traversing the
directory tree with `find` or similar tools, because I did already
that and it seems that there are hidden files that are not found by those
tools. I want a tool that directly iterates on the inodes of the
filesystem.

CONTEXT: I have a problem with my quota in a CentOS 7.9 server. I have
a given quota of 1100GB on a certain filesystem `/share/storage` and my
used space is growing permanently at a rate of 100MB per minute
(approx), even if I am not logged in the server, neither there are
processes owned by me. So I have now almost all the space
exhausted. But, if I do a `$ du /share/storage/user`, it reports just
556GB.

I know that there may  files that are owned by me but they may live in
other directories (for instance `/tmp` or other directories in other
users accounts). I checked all that, and I didn't find anything.

I have checked for open files being written with `lsof` and I didn't find
anything neither.

So my idea is to have the list of inodes and the sizes of those files,
and then compare it with the list after a certain time.

NOTES:
I have root access to the server.

The server is the frontend for a HPC cluster, so the computing nodes
may be writing via NFS on the filesystem. However, I checked that
there are not currently processes in the computing nodes.

Comment: What filesystem? Do you have `quotacheck` on your system?

Comment: The FS is ext4. We do have quotacheck, but I am somewhat reluctant to use it, because I should have to stop the cluster (I'm not completely sure of this). Second, the drift between the "du" and the "quota" values is constantly growing. So it is not a fact that there is some mismatch that can be fixed running quotacheck.

Comment: Is the amount of disk space reported by df going down by roughly 100MB a minute or not?

Comment: @icarus I can't tell because it is a server used as frontend in a HPC cluster and it is constantly being used by other people, so the disk usage fluctuates a lot. I will try to check again that. Tanks!

Answer (score 0):

We have found the problem. There was a process running in a computing node that kept writing to a file (it reached >500GB of size). The directory corresponding to that file was deleted in the frontend, and for some reason the process kept writing to the file from the computing node. Once the process was killed the space of the file was released.

So, I recommend in this cases to look for stale processes in the computing node.

**EDIT**: Regarding the question that I posted (traversing all the inodes without traversing the filesystem itself with `find` for instance), I didn't tried but it seems that you can get the number of inodes of the filesystem with df:

```
[mstorti@seshat ~]$ df -i /share/storage/
Filesystem       Inodes    IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1      45753856 26022211 19731645   57% /share/storage
```

Then I guess that you can loop over all the possible inodes (from 1 to 45753856) and then for each inode check for each inode if it is allocated or not (from the shell you can use `debugfs`) and then store all the current inodes and their sizes in a file. Then at a later time, you do the same thing and compare, and luckyly you can find the file that is consuming space.

However, as I sead before I think it's better to use `lsof`, but remember to do that in all the computing nodes in the cluster.